# in android baseadapter, how to hide the section header when no item is in the section

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I use component android-section-list to create sections in my listView, which is using the baseadapter.

The listView shows the artists, and each section groups the artists by their alphabet. Currently in my code, the sections range from a-z and 0-9. But in some cases, some sections do not have a item, therefore it is no need to show the section with no artists.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  

    public final Map<String,Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String,Adapter>();  
    public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;  
    public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;  
    Typeface arialFont, folksFont;
    String activity;

    public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context) {  
        headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);

    }  

    public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {  
        this.headers.add(section);  
        this.sections.put(section, adapter);  
    }  

    public Object getItem(int position) {  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section  
            if(position == 0) return section;  
            if(position < size) return adapter.getItem(position - 1);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    public int getCount() {  
        // total together all sections, plus one for each section header  
        int total = 0;  
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getCount() + 1;  
        return total;  
    }  

    public int getViewTypeCount() {  
        // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections  
        int total = 1;  
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();  
        return total;  
    }  

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {  
        int type = 1;  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section  
            if(position == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;  
            if(position < size) return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
            type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();  
        }  
        return -1;  
    }  

    public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {  
        return false;  
    }  

    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {  
        return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);  
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  


        int sectionnum = 0;
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section  
            if(position == 0) return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);  
            if(position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
            sectionnum++;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    public long getItemId(int position) {  
        return position;  
    }  

}
```

so my question is how to hide the section header when the sections has no items to show, the change is on getView() methods or somewhere else